# Why does ignoring SIGCONT still make a process continue?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, signals, posix

This is my code, ignoring `SIGCONT`:

```c
int main() {
    signal(SIGCONT, SIG_IGN);
    while(1);
}
```

This is what happens:

```
> ./main &
[1] 25093
> kill -STOP 25093

[1]+  Stopped                 ./main
> ps -aux | grep 25093
xxx    25093 98.6  0.0   2488   872 pts/8    T    18:23   0:20 ./main
> kill -CONT 25093
> ps -aux | grep 25093
xxx    25093 52.1  0.0   2488   872 pts/8    R    18:23   0:28 ./main
```

1. It seems that `SIGCONT` still made my process continue. Does it mean that a handler of `SIGCONT` is just a "side-effect"?
2. I wonder at what time `SIGCONT` makes the process run again? At what time is the process put into the dispatch queue again? Is it when the `kill` syscall is performed or when the process is going to be dispatched? (I read a passage about Linux signals that indicates that dispatch code doesn't treat `SIGCONT` specially. The code segment is showed below.)

```c
if (ka->sa.sa_handler == SIG_DFL) { 
  int exit_code = signr; 
 
  /* Init gets no signals it doesn't want.  */ 
  if (current->pid == 1) 
   continue; 
 
  switch (signr) { 
  case SIGCONT: case SIGCHLD: case SIGWINCH: 
   continue; 
 
  case SIGTSTP: case SIGTTIN: case SIGTTOU: 
   if (is_orphaned_pgrp(current->pgrp)) 
    continue; 
   /* FALLTHRU */ 
 
  case SIGSTOP: 
   current->state = TASK_STOPPED; 
   current->exit_code = signr; 
   if (!(current->p_pptr->sig->action[SIGCHLD-1].sa.sa_flags & SA_NOCLDSTOP)) 
    notify_parent(current, SIGCHLD); 
   schedule(); 
   continue; 
 
  case SIGQUIT: case SIGILL: case SIGTRAP: 
  case SIGABRT: case SIGFPE: case SIGSEGV: 
  case SIGBUS: case SIGSYS: case SIGXCPU: case SIGXFSZ: 
   if (do_coredump(signr, regs)) 
    exit_code |= 0x80; 
   /* FALLTHRU */ 
 
  default: 
   sigaddset(&current->pending.signal, signr); 
   recalc_sigpending(current); 
   current->flags |= PF_SIGNALED; 
   do_exit(exit_code); 
   /* NOTREACHED */ 
  } 
 } 
 ... 
 handle_signal(signr, ka, &info, oldset, regs); 
 return 1; 
} 
... 
return 0;
```

Comment: The handling of `SIGCONT` is defined by POSIX and The Open Group. The text was revised to take account of threads in IEEE Std 1003.1TM-2008/Cor 1-2013 (IEEE Standard for Information Technology—Portable Operating System Interface (POSIX®) Base Specifications, Issue 7—Technical Corrigendum 1), see [austin group bug 77](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=77).

Answer (score 6):

This is the intended behavior of `SIGCONT` according to the POSIX standard. Quoting from [POSIX.1-2017 chapter 2](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html), section 2.4 "Signal Concepts", subsection 2.4.1:

> **When `SIGCONT` is generated for a process that is stopped, the process shall be continued, even if the `SIGCONT` signal is ignored by the process or is blocked by all threads within the process and there are no threads in a call to a `sigwait()` function selecting `SIGCONT`.** If `SIGCONT` is blocked by all threads within the process, there are no threads in a call to a `sigwait()` function selecting `SIGCONT`, and `SIGCONT` is not ignored by the process, the `SIGCONT` signal shall remain pending on the process until it is either unblocked by a thread or a thread calls a `sigwait()` function selecting `SIGCONT`, or a stop signal is generated for the process or any of the threads within the process.

You cannot prevent `SIGCONT` from resuming execution of your process. The most you can do is block its delivery, meaning that if you add `SIGCONT` to the set of blocked signals your process will not "notice" it (registered handlers will not run until unblocked), but it will nonetheless resume execution.

---

In Linux, the "continuing" action of `SIGCONT` is performed right away on signal generation, i.e. during the `kill` syscall. This is done before even checking if the signal is blocked or ignored. The code responsible for this is in [`prepare_signal()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.0/source/kernel/signal.c#L906):

```c
/*
 * Handle magic process-wide effects of stop/continue signals. Unlike
 * the signal actions, these happen immediately at signal-generation
 * time regardless of blocking, ignoring, or handling.  This does the
 * actual continuing for SIGCONT, but not the actual stopping for stop
 * signals. The process stop is done as a signal action for SIG_DFL.
 *
 * Returns true if the signal should be actually delivered, otherwise
 * it should be dropped.
 */
static bool prepare_signal(int sig, struct task_struct *p, bool force)
{
    // ...

    } else if (sig == SIGCONT) {
        unsigned int why;
        /*
         * Remove all stop signals from all queues, wake all threads.
         */
        siginitset(&flush, SIG_KERNEL_STOP_MASK);
        flush_sigqueue_mask(&flush, &signal->shared_pending);
        for_each_thread(p, t) {
            flush_sigqueue_mask(&flush, &t->pending);
            task_clear_jobctl_pending(t, JOBCTL_STOP_PENDING);
            if (likely(!(t->ptrace & PT_SEIZED))) {
                t->jobctl &= ~JOBCTL_STOPPED;
                wake_up_state(t, __TASK_STOPPED);
            } else
                ptrace_trap_notify(t);
        }

    // ...
}
```